# How to change storage class In S3 the fastest way

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have around 7 TB of data in a folder in Amazon S3. I want to change the storage class from standard to one zone IA. But when it's done via UI its taking too long, might even take whole day. What's the fastest way to change the storage class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [Lifecycle Policy for an S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html).

This can automatically change the storage class for objects older than a given number of days.

So, this is the "fastest" way for you to *request* the change.

However, the Lifecycle policy might take up to 24-48 hours to complete, so it might not be the "fastest" to have all the objects transitioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, John. But i have it in a folder inside a bucket. I believe we can put policy only on bucket not on a specific folder isn't it?

Comment: You can specify a **prefix** for the lifecycle policy. This is equivalent to a "folder". (Folders don't actually exist in S3, they are merely stored as part of object Keys.)

Comment: @SrihariKaranth it sounds like you have a "folder" that you want to *exclude* from a lifecycle policy affecting the rest of the bucket.  That is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it different ways:

1. Via the console as you experienced
2. Via lifecycle management
3. Via AWS cli
4. Via AWS SDK (if you know any of the programming language)

You can also change the storage class of an object that is already stored in Amazon S3 to any other storage class by making a copy of the object using the PUT Object - Copy API.

You copy the object in the same bucket using the same key name and specify request headers as follows:

> Set the x-amz-metadata-directive header to COPY.
>
> Set the x-amz-storage-class to the storage class that you want to use.

**In a versioning-enabled bucket, you cannot change the storage class of a specific version of an object. When you copy it, Amazon S3 gives it a new version ID.**

Option 4 would be the fastest way in my case (as a developer). Looping through all the objects and copy them with the correct storage class.

Hope it helps!